# Error running a Maven project for Spring MVC due to 'pom.xml' file?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

**I am creating a Maven project for Spring MVC, and I get the following error(s) when I run it. First when I right-click on the project's name, then select 'Run As', and then choose 'Maven build…' (with Goals: jetty:run)**

```
[WARNING] Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext@51671b08{/mvcDemo,C:\Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1035)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6MavenConfiguration.parseAnnotations(Jetty6MavenConfiguration.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configure(AbstractConfiguration.java:119)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.AbstractConfiguration.configureWebApp(AbstractConfiguration.java:96)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration.configureWebApp(Configuration.java:124)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1217)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:110)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:371)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:307)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

**When I try to right-click on the project's name again, select 'Run As', then choose 'Maven clean', and then do 'Maven build...' (with Goals: jetty:run), I receive the error(s) like below:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project mvcDemo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[3,37] error: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[4,29] error: package org.springframework.ui does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[5,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[6,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[7,46] error: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[9,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[10,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[19,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[37,85] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[51,91] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[18,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[37,23] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[36,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[51,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] \Users\7d0\Desktop\Eclipse\WORKSPACE\PROJECTS\mvcDemo\src\main\java\org\mvcDemo\Controllers\MvcControllers.java:[50,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**I have added the following .jar files in Java Build Path:**

```
jetty-6.1.26.jar, 
jetty-plus-6.1.26.jar, 
maven-hudson-plugin-6.1.7.jar, 
org.mortbay.jetty.util.jar, 
plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar, 
spring-agent-2.5.6.jar, 
classmate-1.0.0.jar, 
hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, 
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, 
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, 
commons-logging-1.2.jar, 

All .jar files in spring-framework-4.1.4.RELEASE/libs/ folder 
(spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar, ...)
```

**Below is my 'pom.xml' file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>springMvcDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvcDemo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>mvcDemo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>    
 </dependencies>
<build>
   <finalName>mvcDemo</finalName>    
<plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-javaagent C:/Users/7d0/Desktop/Eclipse/Spring MVC Demo/JARs/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar</argLine>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-javaagent C:/Users/7d0/Desktop/Eclipse/Spring MVC Demo/JARs/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar</argLine>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>    
 </build>
 </project>
```

**How can I fix the error(s)? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What is inside your *pom.xml*?

Comment: Please add your pom.xml.

Comment: I have added my 'pom.xml'. What should I change for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are failing to run because none of the spring dependencies are in your maven build/run classpath.

Adding all the jars to your project build path isn't going to do anything for you when you choose to "run as -> maven project" because maven is going to use the classpath in the pom, ignoring everything you have setup in your IDE.

You should modify the pom file so that it includes the dependencies that you have added to your project build path.  You can use the m2e eclipse plugin and import the project as a maven project and it will take care of managing your build classpath using the dependencies specified in your pom file, then you won't have to manage them in two different places.

Comment: Can you show me how to include the dependencies for the JAR files that I have added in Java Build Path and use m2e eclipse plugin that you mentioned above? Sorry, I am new to Maven. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the classes are not loaded in build path. update your maven project by right click project-->Maven-->Update project--->Force update snapshot and then try it.

Comment: I tried to update Maven project with Force update snapshot, but I still receive the error. Any other idea? Thanks.